# Case When Rule-based Symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, rule-based

I am using the Expression in Symbology.

I have these attributes:

- **Num_blows** which has specific numbers 30-40, next I have the
- **Blow Counts** (Named as Set_1 up to Set_60).

If the Num_Blows is 30, there are values from Set_1 to Set_30 and set_31 to Set_60 is 0. I'm filtering the data so all Blows with <=4 will be shown. I'm currently using the code below,

```
case

    when "Num_blows" <> 0 and "Set_2" - "Set_1" <= 4 then '2'

end
```

[image]

The resulting symbology includes all Set_## with 0 values.

[image]

How should I write the formula that uses the values from Num_Blows and not include the 0 values?

---

I figured it out.

I added the numbers starting from 2 up to 55 so all values within these numbers will appear.
[image]

I can't really translate what I want to do but I did some trial and error, and it works.

This is the result I got,

The points are from the dynamic compaction.

- The colored points have specific range of blows.
  [image]
- Color Red Diamond shows the differences of the last two blows that are >=70mm
- Color Blue Diamond show the differences of the last two blows that are <=4mm
- The Yellow Circle with # shows the specific blows with <=4mm
- The Green Circle with # shows the specific blows with >=70mm

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Can you specify a bit more what do you want your Style to represent overall (as an edit to the question)?   Just Boolean show/no show, or a value related to the greatest Num_Blows?  You might want to have a look at the array_agg() or count() functions, depending on your need you might not need a rule based symbology, just a single  expression symbology. Another possible approach could be to add computed columns to your Layer attribute table to represent the max Set value and if the latest increment is > 4, then directly use these values in the style

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do, but maybe cycling through all the fields will work for you, I have a post about it which you can find [here](https://bogind.blogspot.com/2022/07/exploring-qgis-expression-engine-part-9.html), you can check if each field name starts with `Set_` to see if you need it for your expression.

Comment: Let `Num_Blow = 30`, `Set_55 = 8`, `Set_54 = 5` and `Set_xx = 0` where `xx` is in range `[31,60]`. `Set_55 - Set_54` is indeed `<= 4` so your last symbology rule is true, but it doesn't mean it will change vales for these `Set_31` to `Set_60`. They are simply not considered in your expression as it only relies on `Set_55` and `Set_54` to chose what to display. Can you confirm this behaviour? Can you also show some of the data?

Comment: In such cases it always helps to include sample data 1) to better understand what you want to do 2) to help testing without first doing the whole work of recreating your data and settings. Additionally, you should add more information about what you want to do. As it is written now, the question is unclear.

Comment: At the moment your question includes your answer to it. Please cut/paste that into the area reserved for answers. It is fine to self-answer questions but not in the area reserved for the question.